# What to do when the question that is a "duplicate" does not contain the needed answer

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

My [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27716/if-the-aircraft-altitude-is-not-controlled-by-pilot-or-autopilot-would-it-be-st) has recently been closed as a duplicate of [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12507/what-does-it-mean-for-a-plane-to-be-aerodynamically-stable) much broader question.

While the "duplicate" question does mention altitude as well, it does not contain the needed answer. It is much broader question and the answers do not focus enough on that I would like to know. One mentions that the stability I would like to know above "***can be*** achieved", this is not the answer on how it ***is*** on a typical plane.

Is it appropriate to nominate the question for reopening, or some other action would be more appropriate? It is very unlikely that the new better answer would appear for the "duplicate" during any reasonable time.

Answer (score 7):

When you get enough rep (I think 1500 but I'm not sure) you can certainly nominate it for reopening. But I doubt you'll get much help (four other people have to agree to reopen) because I do think your question was answered in the linked dupe. Basically your question is about aerodynamic altitude stability and the answers to the broader question address this sufficiently. I copied the relevant quote into the comments on your question.

You can edit your question to refine it to specifically what you feel you're not getting. That's the best way to get it reopened,

If you still don't think that answers it I have successfully garnered reopen support before at [the hangar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar).

I know getting your questions closed is frustrating but it keeps the site from getting bloated. If the answer is already there it's better to direct people to it so information stays consistent. I've had several closed myself. Sometime I agree and when I didn't I found I can usually refine it to the part that I didn't think was answered.

Comment: It is 500 to open and close questions for now. http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: Note that since the redesign of the site, it is now 3000 (up from 500)